# Unable to send message to Lync Online Account Office 365 using UCMA 4.0 SDK

Tags: c#, ucma, lync-2013, lync-client-sdk

I am unable to send an IM message using UCMA 4.0 SDK I have followed all the Steps given in the below video tutorial, But alas no success. 
I am using UCMASampleHelper class as mentioned in the below video tutorial.So please help me debug this issue as i have never used the UCMA 4.0 SDK before to send IM. 
When I use the Lync Client SDK from C# i have no issues in sending the IM.
The deployment server will not have any lync client installed on its machine.

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/UCMA-Hello-World-Send-an-Instant-Message

I getting the below error
[image]

I have the following credentials
ServerFQDN: (office365 online server)
UserURI:    (Lync Email address)
Password:   (Lync Email Password)

it gives me the error "No such host found". But my client say this is the correct FQDN

Comment: Seems like you have either a DNS issue and the FQDN cannot be resolved or the target is not accessible,
Are you able to connect with the same credentials and configuration from the same machine?

Comment: The Lync is hosted on Microsoft server (i.e office 365) and the FQDN is "MyCompanyname.microsoft.com". I do not have access to that machine. But whenever I ping "MyCompanyname.microsoft.com" it cannot resolve the FQDN.

Comment: so you have the problem with the FQDN.

Comment: Yes! But My client says it is correct FQDN. I read somewhere that Microsoft does not allow to Send UCMA conversation to Office 365 online instance but i cannot confirm it. I am just looking for a solution. as UCWA (web access) cannot be used to send IM conversation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on the article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn466090(v=office.15).aspx, the API doesn’t apply to Lync Online and it’s not officially supported in Office 365 at this moment.
Posted by Neo Yu MSFT Support

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/166/t/266106.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you should be using sipdir.online.lync.com:443 for the server FQDN and port for Office365.

Second, you have to use a valid Lync client useragent string (e.g. "UCCAPI/4.0.7577.0 OC/4.0.7577.0 (Microsoft Lync 2010)") when setting up your CollaborationPlatform, as the Office365 Lync servers seem to have a very conservative client-type block policy.

Third, Office 365 only uses TLS-DSK authentication.  UCMA only allows NTLM and Kerberos, so it is unlikely that you will ever be able to connect to Office365 Lync until UCMA is updated with TLS-DSK support.  If you get poking around in the Microsoft.Rtc.Collaboration assembly with Reflector, it appears that there was some intention of supporting this, but it was never finished or taken out before the library was released.